# Make View Models activation aware in Prism/Composite MVVM WPF application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

In my MVVMC application I have a process which contains multiple steps, basically a wizard.

My controller resolves my outer View (call it `WizardView`) and adds it to the main region.

`WizardView` contains a breadcrumb trail to show the progress through the wizard and a sub Region to load other views into (call this `WizardRegion`). `Step1View` is the first View loaded into `WizardRegion`.

Each view has it's ViewModel injected into the constructor using the Unity container.

`WizardViewModel` subscribes to several event aggregation events which are published by the step view models.

As each step is completed the View Model publishes an event which `WizardViewModel` uses to store the state, this means `WizardViewModel` is collecting the data from each step as we progress. The step ViewModel also calls the controller to load the next step into `WizardRegion`.

At the final step `WizardViewModel` saves the result of the wizard and the `MainRegion` is navigated back to some other screen.

The next time we enter the wizard, we create a new instance of all the Views and ViewModels but the event subscriptions from the previous wizard still exist.

How can I make my view models aware that they're de-activated so I can unsubscribe my events?

Another option would be to unsubscribe from the event in the event handler. This will probably work but will add complexity when I step back in the wizard and need to re-subscribe to the events again.

Comment: It looks like you are using Unity for DI. Is that true?  If so, are you registering your classes as instances or singletons?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Unity. I'm registering my views and view models as instances. They were originally registered as singletons but it was causing bugs when the wizard was re-entered. If I go back to registering the views and view models as Singltons then I still need to handle some sort of de-activation in the view-model to reset the state for the next time around the wizard. I don't know what the recommended lifetime is for views and view models.

Comment: The lifetime is whatever makes sense for the app.  I use both depending on the logic.  Does your instance view-model still handle the event after its been 'unloaded'?  Does its ~finalizer() fire?

Comment: I've not got a finalizer, I'll give that a go and let you know.

Comment: Finalizer doesn't fire, I suspect that's because it fires on GC and not on the object going out of scope.

Comment: It has to fire at some time?  Maybe the events haven't been GC'd when you are instances are created?

Comment: Finalizer fires when the class is garbage collected. GC doesn't run until memory is low aka disposal is not deterministic.

Comment: implement [IActiveAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.iactiveaware_members(v=pandp.40).aspx) interface on your VM. You can look for example [here](http://not-now-nigel.blogspot.cz/2011/09/using-iactiveaware-and-inavigationaware.html)

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix thanks, someone on the MSDN forum also suggested IActiveAware. I'd already implemented it manually by attaching to the Unloaded event in the view and casting the DataContext to my own IDeactivateable interface but have reverted to IActiveAware. Thanks

Comment: @BenCr Well I'm glad it's solved :) you should provide the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to implement `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.IActiveAware` in my View Model.

```
public bool IsActive
{
    get { return _isActive; }
    set
    {
        if (_isActive != value)
        {
            _isActive = value;
            DoActiveChangedWork(value);
        }
    }
}

public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;
```

It's also possible to implement this in the View but it's not a requirement.

Comment: I don't think it has to be implemented in both View and VM. It's totally enough to implement it in your VM. IsActive is set by RegionBehavior. You just check if the value is false and then you unsubscribe from your events... just sayin' :) Please correct me if I am wrong and also I would say there is no need to fire that IsActiveChanged event since there is no need for subscribers.

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix I guessed that might be the case but haven't tested it yet. I also don't understand why they use that `= delegate { };` syntax at the end of their event definition. I should clean up this answer with a nicer code example and remove the link when I've got time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Prism EventAggregator - you can set `keepSubscriberReferenceAlive` parameter to `false` so it will use a weak reference under the hood so everything will be "unsubscribed" automatically by GC when an object will "die".

```
fundAddedEvent.Subscribe(FundAddedEventHandler, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

otherwise you have to do it yourself by explicitly unsubscribing:

```
fundAddedEvent.Unsubscribe(FundAddedEventHandler);
```

Comment: I am using Prism, sorry I added the tag but didn't make it clear in the question. I was under the impression that the default behaviour was to use a weak reference.

Comment: The keepSubscriberReferenceAlive flag hasn't had any effect. The instance which was subscribed may not be referenced any more but it's not been garbage collected so the event still fires again. I need to find a way to de-activate the view-model